# get selected item id from listview

Tags: android, mysql, listview

I am very new in android.I want a get and store item id which is selected from list view.And that item list already retrieve from mysql database.How can I do that?
This is my code.

**ProjectSelect**

```
public class ProjectSelect extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar mToolbar;
int sempid;
private ListView ProjectList;
String a;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_project_select);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.project_select_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("SELECT A PROJECT");

    GlobalVariable g = (GlobalVariable)getApplicationContext();
    sempid=g.getEmpid();
    Log.d("project emp",sempid+"");


    ProjectList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.projectSelect);
    getProject("http://www.mybusket.com/pmsapp/webs/get_all_project.php?vempid="+sempid+"");
}

private void getProject(final String webUrlService){
    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            try {
                LoadIntoListView(s);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(webUrlService);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                String json;
                while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(json + "\n");
                }
                return sb.toString().trim();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    GetJSON getJSON = new GetJSON();
    getJSON.execute();
}

private void LoadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException{
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    if (jsonObject != null){
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("project");
        final String[] project = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i <jsonArray.length(); i ++){
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            project[i] = obj.getString("projectname");
        }
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, project);
        ProjectList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        ProjectList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                a = ProjectList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Log.e("pname",a+"");

            }
        });

    }
}
```

I want to store selected item id in a global variable class.I already retrieve all item from mysql database.Please help me.

Comment: whats the problem you are facing?

Comment: item id specifically you want or the parent layout it(that is holding complete row of listview)

Comment: Create Arraylist/Hashmap and get value respect to position

Comment: I want only item id when clicked on item and that id retrieve in another activity.

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton class with a hasMap and store the values in hasmap temporarily.Whenver you select a value add that to the class and retrieve that when you need.

```
public class IdClass {
    private Map<Integer, String> clickedIDs = new HashMap<>();
    private static IdClass idClass;

    public static IdClass getIdClass() {
        if (idClass == null) {
            idClass = new IdClass();
        }
        return idClass;
    }

    public void addId(int id,String idValue) {
        clickedIDs.put(id,idValue);

    }

    public String getId(int id) {
        return clickedIDs.get(id);
    }
}
```

whenver you are clicking an item

```
ProjectList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

          //Storing inside the IdClass
          IdClass.getIdClass().addId(position,ProjectList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
          Log.e("pname",a+"");

      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
final String[] project = new String[jsonArray.length()];

final String[] projectId = new String[jsonArray.length()]; // create array to store id

for (int i = 0; i <jsonArray.length(); i ++){
        JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        project[i] = obj.getString("projectname");

        projectId[i] = obj.getString("projectid");// stroe id
    }
```

and finally on item click write below

```
 a = projectId[postion];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do one thing setClickListener to every view on which you are interested in getting id. When call back method of that view is called it will return a view as mentioned in below code.

```
ivMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //when this method is called use below code
             v.getId();
        }
    })
```

If you want to get id of the view that is on Activity then you can do one more thing. Set this below attribute to those view in which you are interested in getting id

```
android:onClick="someMethod"
```

When you click the view those have above attribute it will call the method as mentioned in attribute. you need to define the method in your activity as mentioned below

```
public void someMethod(View view) {
     view.getId(); //and done
}
```